# Is there any throughput limit for external components in ejabberd?

Tags: java, xmpp, ejabberd, whack

I'm trying to scale an external xmpp java whack component with ejabberd. its not going beyond 250msg/sec throughput. is there any limit for external component in ejabberd?

Comment: Have you read http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/?

Comment: yes. Whack lib is sending the packets to ejabberd via a socket synchronously. Why is this?. Why can't they open a new socket each time so that the number of concurrent messages is high?

Answer (score 0):

The connection between external component and ejabberd is via TCP socket. this has to be synced on both ends.
This ends up decreasing the throughput of the external component. We need to open multiple external component sockets to increase the throughput.